# States foreach loop not listing all states

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a drop down menu on my site where I want all US states listed. I have an array of states but I can't seem to get ALL of them to load into my `<option>` tag. Below is the first 15 states as an array and my `<select>` code. Eventually the drop down will link to separate pages for each state with an image of that state (that is why I have an "img" within each state array). The only states I get to load in the drop down are: Alaska, Arkansas, Colorado, Delaware, Florida, Hawaii, and Illinois.

[image]

```
<?php
$states = array();
$states['AL'] = array (
    "name" => "Alabama",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/al.png"
);
$states['AK'] = array (
    "name" => "Alaska",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/ak.png"
);
$states['AZ'] = array (
    "name" => "Arizona",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/az.png"
);
$states['AR'] = array (
    "name" => "Arkansas",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/ar.png"
);
$states['CA'] = array (
    "name" => "California",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/ca.png"
);
$states['CO'] = array (
    "name" => "Colorado",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/co.png"
);
$states['CT'] = array (
    "name" => "Connecticut",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/ct.png"
);
$states['DE'] = array (
    "name" => "Delaware",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/de.png"
);
$states['DC'] = array (
    "name" => "District of Columbia",
    "img" => "http://pharmacoding.com/dendreon/provenge/images/dc.png"
);
$states['FL'] = array (
    "name" => "Florida",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/fl.png"
);
$states['GA'] = array (
    "name" => "Georgia",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/ga.png"
);
$states['HI'] = array (
    "name" => "Hawaii",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/hi.png"
);
$states['ID'] = array (
    "name" => "Idaho",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/id.png"
);
$states['IL'] = array (
    "name" => "Illinois",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/il.png"
);
$states['IN'] = array (
    "name" => "Indiana",
    "img" => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/in.png"
);
?>

<select>
<?php 
foreach($states as $state) {
echo "<option value='state.php?id=" . $state["id"] . ">" . $state["name"] . "</option>";
};
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you ever define `$state["id"]` that you're using in the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing ``' quote, next to the option tag’s closing bracket right after `$state["id"]`.

```
<?php 
foreach($states as $state) {
echo "<option value='state.php?id=" . $state["id"] . "'>" . $state["name"] . "</option>";
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the most immediate question, you are missing a closing quote when you set `<option>`. Then you are setting `$state["id"]` when that key doesn’t exist in the structure you have. You should be using the actual key in that array.

So with that in mind, here is my re-factored version of the code. Note you can use string substitution with double quotes (`"`) so no need for concatenation. Which makes this easier to read and debug as well.

```
echo '<select>';
foreach($states as $state_key =>  $state_value) {
echo "<option value='state.php?id=$state_key'>"
   . $state_value["name"]
   . "</option>"
   ;
};
echo '</select>';
```

That said, you can simplify your code by using an array like this:

```
$states = array();
$states['al'] = array('name' => 'Alabama');
$states['ak'] = array('name' => 'Alaska');
$states['az'] = array('name' => 'Arizona');
$states['ar'] = array('name' => 'Arkansas');
$states['ca'] = array('name' => 'California');
$states['co'] = array('name' => 'Colorado');
$states['ct'] = array('name' => 'Connecticut');
$states['de'] = array('name' => 'Delaware');
$states['de'] = array('name' => 'Delaware');
$states['dc'] = array('name' => 'District of Columbia');
$states['fl'] = array('name' => 'Florida');
$states['ga'] = array('name' => 'Georgia');
$states['hi'] = array('name' => 'Hawaii');
$states['id'] = array('name' => 'Idaho');
$states['il'] = array('name' => 'Illinois');
$states['in'] = array('name' => 'Indiana');

echo '<select>';
foreach($states as $state_key =>  $state_value) {
  $states[$state_key] = array_merge($states[$state_key], array('img' => "http://getwidgetsfree.com/images/state_png/$state_key.png"));
  $state_key_uc = strtoupper($state_key);
  echo "<option value='state.php?id=$state_key_uc'>"
     . $state_value['name']
     . "</option>"
     ;
};
echo '</select>';
```

The goal is you are starting out with a basic array that has the lowercase state code for the array key. Then set the `name` as you did before. But when you do the `foreach` loop, then you just set the `img` value & merge that using `array_merge` into the existing array.